# PHP foreach loop based filtering on XML document

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to filter out each XML category string of a specific category. 
How would I get this working?

For example I just want the x elements from the category Category1.

Example XML:

```
<store id="1" name="store">
    <species name="stud">
        <Category1 name="Category1">
            <x category="Hairs" id="20098288"/>
            <x category="Hairs" id="20098289"/>
        </Category1>
        <Category2 name="Category2">
            <x category="Shirts" id="24342342"/>
            <x category="Shirts" id="24342342"/>
        </Category2>
        <Category3 name="Category3">
            <x category="Jackets" id="423423423"/>
            <x category="Jackets" id="423423423"/>
        </Category3>
    </species>
</store>
```

My actual code, which would let me access every category's child elements:

```
<?php

    foreach($xmlDocument->species as $species_elem){
        foreach($species_elem->attributes() as $child){
            foreach ($child->x as $item){
                $itemID = $item->attributes()->id;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

But I want to specify a Category which only should be access able. For example

> $category = 'Category1';

Pseudo code:

```
<?php

foreach($species as $species_elem){
    foreach($species_elem which contains $Category1 as $category){
        foreach ($child->x as $item){
            $itemID = $item->attributes()->id;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output would be  <x category="Hairs" id="20098288"/> <x category="Hairs" id="20098289"/> from Category1

Comment: When doing `foreach($species_elem->attributes() as $child)`, shouldn't `$child` contain the value of the `name` attribute of `<Category1>`? http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php#refsect1-simplexmlelement.attributes-examples

Comment: It does, but it brings every Categorys child's with it. I just need the child's of a specific Category. This is a Example XML document: http://zwinky.pr0b.com/item/stores/20037336/stud.xml which i try to filter out a specific category, for example i just want the x elements to show from the category Hairs instead of showing the whole x childs from Hairs  and facialhairs .

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Paul Crovella is a good one. XPath is the way to go.

However, node names should not be numbered. If you can change the format I would suggest to change them to a more generic one like 'category'.

Use the `name` attribute to filter the category elements.

## XPath Step By Step

Select the `store` document element node:
`/store`

Its `species` child elements:
`/store/species`

Any child element node (`Category1`, `Category2`, ...):
`/store/species/*`

If the attribute `name` is `Category1`:
`/store/species/*[@name = 'Category1']`

Their `x` child elements:
`/store/species/*[@name = 'Category1']/x`

## DOM

In DOM you you use `DOMXPath::evaluate()` or `DOMXPath::query()` to execute XPath expressions on a DOM.

```
$category = 'Category1';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate("/store/species/*[@name='$category']/x") as $node) {
  echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<x category="Hairs" id="20098288"/>
<x category="Hairs" id="20098289"/>
```

## SimpleXML

SimpleXML uses the SimpleXMLElement::xpath() method. The expression are executed in the context of the element. (`store`) and the result is converted into an array of SimpleXMLElement objects.

```
$category = 'Category1';
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($element->xpath("species/*[@name='$category']/x") as $child) {
  echo $child->asXml(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the XML document you present in your question it's actually pretty straight forward (in your specific case):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($xml->species->Category1->x as $x) {
    echo ' - ', $x->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
 - <x category="Hairs" id="20098288"/>
 - <x category="Hairs" id="20098289"/>
```

You could then parametrize this with a variable for the category:

```
$category = 'Category1';
foreach ($xml->species->$category->x as $x) {
    ...
```

However this actually should have some error handling:

```
$elements = $xml->species->$category;

if ($elements) foreach ($elements->x as $x) {
    echo ' - ', $x->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

as the element named by the variable might not always exist. The value will be `null` then.

The full example:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP foreach loop based filtering on XML document
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/29280839/367456
 */

$buffer = <<<XML
<store id="1" name="store">
    <species name="stud">
        <Category1 name="Category1">
            <x category="Hairs" id="20098288"/>
            <x category="Hairs" id="20098289"/>
        </Category1>
        <Category2 name="Category2">
            <x category="Shirts" id="24342342"/>
            <x category="Shirts" id="24342342"/>
        </Category2>
        <Category3 name="Category3">
            <x category="Jackets" id="423423423"/>
            <x category="Jackets" id="423423423"/>
        </Category3>
    </species>
</store>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($xml->species->Category1->x as $x) {
    echo ' - ', $x->asXML(), "\n";
}

$category = 'Category1';

foreach ($xml->species->$category->x as $x) {
    echo ' - ', $x->asXML(), "\n";
}

$elements = $xml->species->$category;

if ($elements) foreach ($elements->x as $x) {
    echo ' - ', $x->asXML(), "\n";
}
```